# Microcontroller web server

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

suppose A & B wants to communicate through internet, we brought internet from ISP, and their Ip is not visible from remote computer, but then how application like team viewer works on our computer.
this is only possible if i host a web site with a Ip which is visible to A & B,
then A place it's data to C and B will read it from C.
A----<-->----C-----<-->------B

i want to know is this the right way?
how team viewer,skype application communicates from pc-to-pc

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is usually that A&B would send a request to a relay server which is visible to both. As the requests are outgoing, the ISP doesn't require A or B to support incoming requests.

The simplest implementation is for the server to then act as an intermediary between the two. This creates some additional latency and server load.

Alternatively, the server may tell B or A try to create a connection to the other client. If either connection is possible - one of A or B's ISP is configured to allow incoming requests - then the conversation continues with the direct connection rather than being relayed through the server.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, but it's not just the IP. Due to Firewalls, routers and so on you might want C to be able to handle all the traffic (and buffer it). C cannot rely on simply exchanging IP addresses.